# ItextSharp Font.BaseFont returning Null for some fonts

Tags: c#, fonts, itext

Im using `font.BaseFont` to get the `BaseFont` of the fonts registered using

```
var fontPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot") + "\\fonts\\"+fontname+".ttf";
FontFactory.Register(fontPath);
```

In most cases it works but in case of some fonts it return Null.Why is that?

EDIT 1:

The new `Font` is created using

```
     FontFactory.GetFont(fontName, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

then i use `font.BaseFont` to get the BaseFont so that i can set the `Font` for `Overcontent`

Comment: Did you verify that you actually have those fonts available on your computer?

Comment: Also: `FontFactory` is about creating `Font` objects whereas the question is about `BaseFont`. This needs clarification. The question is incomplete.

Comment: @KevinHendricks Yes these fonts are shown by Font Selection Dialogue

Comment: How do you know `fontname` is the actual PostScript name of the font? I'll post an answer with an example.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie What im using is GTK# FontSelectionButton.It returns FontName(Name+Size),i use a regex expression to get the fontname and fontsize.Since GTK Widget is returning the FontName i expect it to be correct.

Comment: The example I refer to shows that there's more than one name inside a font: http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part3/chapter11/font_factory.pdf Make sure you use the right name!

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, the actual name of the font is different from the file name used for the font. You need to check which names are registered with `FontFactory` as explained in my book. See http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C11 for some examples; in that example we have a font `cmr10` of which the name is `Computer Modern Regular`. You won't get that font if you use the `GetFont()` method with `cmr10`.

This is an example that add the name of the registered fonts as a `Paragraph` to a `Document` using that specific font:

```
foreach (String f in FontFactory.RegisteredFonts) {
    document.Add(new Paragraph(f, FontFactory.GetFont(f, "", BaseFont.EMBEDDED)));
}
```

If you don't want to depend on the real name, you could also register each font using an alias (look for the appropriate `Register()` method).

Comment: On the window creating event i call a method called Register Fonts,this method will Register all fonts(with extension .ttf in the Windows Fonts Folder) using FontFactory.Regsiter(fontpath)

Comment: I've updated my answer. Maybe you want to use an alias of your own choice instead of the actual PostScript name. That's all documented in my book, isn't it?

Comment: I register all fonts in Fonts folder with FontFactory.Then a user is given a choice to select a font from the GTK font dialog.I then try to create a Font using the fontname and get the basefont to use with the overcontent.I dont understand why there is a conflict with names

Comment: Give us an example of a font program that is registered of which the isn't returned (because its null). Please improve the question with an example that allows us to understand the problem. Otherwise nobody will be able to answer the question.

Comment: I have added all the needed code.Please see the edit,hope everything is clear now

Comment: Is the `font` null or `bf`? You're still ignoring my remark that what you think is the font name may be different from the basefont name. If you keep ignoring that, I may lose interest in trying to answering your question.

Comment: Bf is null.I have added a comment in the line that results in error.do you need a specific font name that causes the error? I did not get what you are saying.

Comment: Aha, and all answer and comments started from the assumption that `Font` was `null`. Do you see a `GetCalculatedBaseFont()` method? That's probably the method you should use.

Comment: I will try tommorow and get back ,its midnight now.I feel great that itext author itself is helping me out.Thanks :)

Comment: I'm in New York right now, so for me it's early afternoon ;-)

Comment: I tried using GetCalculatedBaseFont(),now the base-font is not null.But in case of problematic fonts instead of showing an error,default font is used.